# Using Proxy for WebRequest in Powershell

Tags: web-services, powershell, proxy, webrequest, connectivity

I use WebRequest in a script powershell for check url is valid and detect webservice is available.

My script WebRequest

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($WebServiceSSRSRDL)
$request.Method = 'HEAD'

$request.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
if ($request.Proxy -ne $null) 
{
    $request.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
}

$response = $request.GetResponse()
$httpStatus = $response.StatusCode
$urlIsValid = ($httpStatus -eq 'OK')
$tryError = $null
$response.Close()
```

But I get the error **The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.**

If I use WebClient I get not error, all is OK.

My script WebClient

```
$webclient = New-Object Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
if($webclient.Proxy -ne $null)     
{
   $webclient.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
}

$webclient.DownloadString($WebServiceSSRSRDL) | Out-Null
```

I would like use WebRequest in my script. Any suggestions about it ?